# Creating a function to replace strings that have been gotten from an XML file

Tags: php, xml

I am creating a function that replaces certain parts of a string with predefined constants, for this I have created this function:

```
<?php

function ReplaceWithPath($string)
{
    $toReplace = ["~~BASEPATH~~" => ABSPATH, "~~LIBPATH~~" => LIBPATH];

    foreach ($toReplace as $replace => $replacement)
    {
        if (preg_match($replace, $string))
            return str_replace($replace, $replacement, $string);
        else
            continue;
    }
    return false;
}

?>
```

But for some reason, when I use it it does not give me a proper result, but instead `boolean false`.

I am using the function in my config file as such:

```
<?php

$cfg_file = str_replace("\\", "/", dirname(__FILE__)) . "/web.config.xml";
$cfg = simplexml_load_file($cfg_file);

define("ABSPATH", $cfg->paths->basepath);

require_once 'library/functions/ReplaceWithString.php';
define("LIBPATH", ReplaceWithPath($cfg->paths->libpath));
var_dump(LIBPATH);

?>
```

The part of the XML file in question is this:

```
<paths>
  <basepath>E:/projects/php/site/site/</basepath>
  <libpath>~~BASEPATH~~library/</libpath>
  <classpath>~~LIBPATH~~class/</classpath>
  <traitpath>~~LIBPATH~~trait/</traitpath>
</paths>
```

I need to be able to change the parts that are `~~BASEPATH~~` with `ABSPATH` but it just return `boolean false`.

**Edit**

After testing, I have found that it is the fact that there are multiple constants in the array (`$toReplace`) that is causing this not to work. WHY IT DO DIS?!?!?!

New function created:

```
function ReplacePathPart($path)
{
    $replaced = "";
    $toReplace = array(
        '!!BASEPATH!!'=>ABSPATH, 
        '!!LIBPATH!!'=>LIBPATH
    );

    foreach ($toReplace as $replace => $replacement)
    {
        $replaced = str_replace($replace, $replacement, $path);
    }

    return $replaced;
}
```

Amended config file:

```
<?php

$cfg_file = str_replace("\\", "/", dirname(__FILE__)) . "/config/web.config.xml";
$cfg = simplexml_load_file($cfg_file);

define("ABSPATH", $cfg->paths->basepath);
require_once 'library/functions/ReplaceWithString.php';
define("LIBPATH", ReplacePathPart($cfg->paths->libpath));
define("CLASSPATH", ReplacePathPart($cfg->paths->classpath));

print ABSPATH . " |abspath<br />";
print LIBPATH . " |libpath<br />";
print CLASSPATH . " |classpath<br />";

?>
```

Output:

> E:/projects/php/site/site/ |abspath
>   !!BASEPATH!!library/ |libpath
>   !!BASEPATH!!library/class/ |classpath

Comment: Doesn't this just work: `$replacedResult = str_replace(array_keys($toReplace), array_values($toReplace), $string);` ?

Comment: BTW: In `~~BASEPATH~~`, `~` will be seen as delimiter for your `preg_match()` call and your regex will fail with unescaped delimiters

Comment: You don't need a loop, `str_replace()` also can take arrays as argument, as I said just use: `$replacedResult = str_replace(array_keys($toReplace), array_values($toReplace), $string);` you overthink this way too much.; Now you use `$path` each source which doesn't change and save it in `$replaced`, that's why only the last one gets replaced

Comment: @Rizier123, I got the wrong end of the stick on that one! My bad and can you add as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are overthinking this way too much. Drinking a cup of coffee(☕) or reading this answer should solve the problem:

First off your original function:

```
function ReplaceWithPath($string)
{
    $toReplace = ["~~BASEPATH~~" => ABSPATH, "~~LIBPATH~~" => LIBPATH];

    foreach ($toReplace as $replace => $replacement)
    {
        if (preg_match($replace, $string))
            return str_replace($replace, $replacement, $string);
        else
            continue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) call [`~`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) will be seen as delimiter for the regex string. So in your strings: `~~BASEPATH~~`, `~~LIBPATH~~` you then have unescaped delimiters, [which means your regex will fail](https://regex101.com/r/xI9vG2/1).

The [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) statement in your foreach loop would immediately stop the function call and would only replace 1 `search => replace` element.

Searching for the search strings and looping through the replacement array is unnecessary. Since with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) you already search for the search strings + you can pass arrays to the function:

> mixed str_replace ( **mixed** $search , **mixed** $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )

Now in your second try you get a bit closer to the solution, but still make some logical mistakes:

```
function ReplacePathPart($path)
{
    $replaced = "";
    $toReplace = array(
        '!!BASEPATH!!'=>ABSPATH, 
        '!!LIBPATH!!'=>LIBPATH
    );

    foreach ($toReplace as $replace => $replacement)
    {
        $replaced = str_replace($replace, $replacement, $path);
    }

    return $replaced;
}
```

You still loop through the replacement array and now you use `$path` as source which will never change and in each iteration you overwrite `$replaced` with the replaced string. So at the end you end up with only replacing the last `search => replace` element.

---

The solution to your problem is simple:

```
function ReplacePathPart($path)
{
    $toReplace = array(
        '!!BASEPATH!!'=>ABSPATH, 
        '!!LIBPATH!!'=>LIBPATH
    );    

    return str_replace(array_keys($toReplace), array_values($toReplace), $path);

}
```

As I said `str_replace()` can take arrays as arguments, so with [`array_keys($toReplace)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) you search for your keys(`!!BASEPATH!!`, `!!LIBPATH!!`) and replace them with the values(`ABSPATH`, `LIBPATH`), which you get with [`array_values($toReplace)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).